# React Route not displaying component on production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, react-router-v4

I am developing a React Webapp and I am using webpack for automating some tasks. The development mode works fine, I can see all components showing up, but when I open index.html from /dist folder where I have bundle.js and bundle.css same directory the webapp does not show the components.

I tried to upload on a apache web server whole /dist folder and tried to access like localhost/dist still I cannot see the comopnents.

Any idea how to make it so the files within dist folder I can use, in fact that's why I am using webpack to automate tasks so I can use this folder for production.

Webpack:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    console.log("ENV DETECTED: " + argv.mode);
    return {
        entry: './src/index.js',
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            filename: 'bundle.js',
            //publicPath: '/', // Remove this when running in production
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "babel-loader"
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.html$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: "html-loader",
                            options: {
                                minimize: true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        // 'style-loader',
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                importLoaders: 1,
                                minimize: true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: {
                                config: {
                                    path: './postcss.config.js'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        argv.mode !== 'production' ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                importLoaders: 1,
                                minimize: true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: {
                                config: {
                                    path: './postcss.config.js'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "sass-loader"
                    ]
                }
            ],
        },
        devServer: {
            historyApiFallback: true,
        },
        plugins: [
            new CleanWebpackPlugin('dist', {}),
            new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
                template: "src/index.html",
                filename: "./index.html"
            }),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: "bundle.css",
                chunkFilename: "bundle.css"
            }),
            require('autoprefixer'),
        ]
    }
};
```

Routes:

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Helloworld from './components/helloworld/helloworld.component';
import SecondView from './components/secondview/secondview.component';
import ThirdView from "./components/thirdview/thirdview.component";

const AppRoutes = () => (
    <main>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Helloworld}/>
            <Route path='/secondview' component={SecondView}/>
            <Route path='/thirdview' component={ThirdView}/>
            <Route path='/thirdview/:number' component={ThirdView}/>
        </Switch>
    </main>
);

export default AppRoutes;
```

Helloworld component:

```
import React from 'react';
import HelloworldApi from './helloworld.api';
import { Link , withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
require('./helloworld.style.scss');

class Helloworld extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            persons: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("I am being called helloworld component...");
        HelloworldApi.getAll().then(response => {
            if (response.data) {
                console.log(response.data);
                const persons = response.data;
                this.setState({persons});
            } else {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={"boxDiv"}>
                <p>Helloworld components</p>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                <h3>Web pack and React aree awesome together!!! test</h3>
                {this.state.persons.map(person => <li>{person.name}</li>)}

                <Link to='/secondview'>go to secondview</Link>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(Helloworld);
```

Comment: Is it just showing a blank white page? If so, I would guess that the issue lies with how your static files are being hosted or a relative path is slightly off. What are the key differences between your development mode and production mode?

Comment: @MichaelSorensen I refere production mode when using files within dist folder, webpack has some task like minifing js and css, transpiling saas to css and so on. so the idea is that how can I be able to use dist folder so I can open webapp using this folder. When running development mode I have no dist folder but instead I use directly the files. so the routing basically works only for development but not production...

Comment: So if i'm understanding this correctly, your webpack is compiling your js and css into your /dev directory. If that's the case, in your index.html file are you linking to those files correctly? e.g. <script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/bundle.js"></script> vs src="bundle.js"

Comment: webpack is compiling code which include js,css within /dist folder. and yes I am linking bundle.js and bundle.css fine, otherwise it would complain about it and show 404 or somthing. the problem here is the routing does not work from dist folder I open index.html from url